# How to Connect to a Git Remote Server with SSH KEY + Passphrase and Different Port Via Script

Tags: git, ssh, remote-server, ssh-keys, git-remote

i have a Webserver listening to **SSH on Port 1234** .
The Webserver uses a public key in `~/.ssh/authorized-keys` For authorisation.
To connect via SSH i have an **private SSH Key with passphrase** On my local machine

now i want this Server to be a git Remote Server, so on the Server i create a bare repo in my home directory with a **nonRootUser**.

```
mkdir ~/project.git
cd ~/project.git
git init --bare
```

Now on my local machinei create a new repo

```
mkdir myProject
cd myProject
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

**FROM A SCRIPT** i want to set the remote to the Webserver and push to it. **And here is where i Stuck**

```
git remote add origin ssh://nonRootUser@WebserverDomain.com:1234/home/project.git
git push origin master
```

this Produces the **Error**

*Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.*

I think i still need to add the passphrase, but dont know how. And the Error still lets open if i'm close to an solution or not because it says make sure the repo exists. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to run once `ssh WebserverDomain.com` from the command line ?

Comment: i can successfully ssh into my Werbserver with  `ssh  -p 1234 nonRootUser@WebserverDomain.com -i /path/to/private/key`       and entering the requested passphrase

Answer (score 1):

Start an SSH agent, or add the key to your existing agent with the following command:

```
ssh-add /path/to/your/key
```

You'll be prompted for the key's passphrase, and it'll be automatically offered for use during SSH authentication.

This article has a decent explanation of what the agent is and what it does, as well as some of the caveats of using one.

https://smallstep.com/blog/ssh-agent-explained/

Comment: thanks, that sounds good. Is there a Way to enter the passphrase from a script instead of typing ist manualy ?

Comment: "*enter the passphrase from a script*: That's meaningless. A passphrase is your **secret** code. If you gonna put a passphrase into a script — you don't need a passphrase at all.

Comment: i was thinking about github actions, there you can use "Secrets" (i know that they are not 100 % safe) I wannt want to keep my passphrase as an github "Secret" and use it in an github action to connect to the webserver but there i get an problem when ssh-add wants the passphrase tipped